# Replace previous text on textBrowser PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

```
textBrowser.append("Type_01")
```

works perfectly but, whenever I am running the program again it adds a new line instead of replacing it.

Comment: From what I understand you is that you want a function that allows you to replace the last line, am I correct?

Comment: check documentation for `textBrowser` maybe it has `clear()` which you could run before `append()`. Or `insert()` which could replace text instead of appending. Or maybe it has `set_text()` ?

Comment: clear() works well before appending. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last line, delete and add a new text with the following code:

```
cursor = textBrowser.textCursor()
cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.LineUnderCursor)
cursor.removeSelectedText()
cursor.insertText(text)
```

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Replace Last Line")
        self.textBrowser.append("Stack\nOverflow\nHello\nWorld")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        lay.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if text:
            self.replace_last_line(text)

    def replace_last_line(self, text):
        cursor = self.textBrowser.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.LineUnderCursor)
        cursor.removeSelectedText()
        cursor.insertText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I used this but unfortunately, it's not working. I used textbowser.clear() before appending and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @AkashKumar mmm, your description is not clear, if you use `clear()` + `append()` then you want to replace all the text that in that case it is better to use `setText()` or `setPlainText()`, in my code just replace the last line that is what I asked in a comment below your question